# How to write a preg_match_all just for grabbing one specific element?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

Until the website give me an access to his API, i need to display only 2 things from this website :

[What i want to grab](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/2783/capturedcran20100930171.png)
// [Example on a live page](http://www.esl.eu/fr/player/5178309/)

**Those 2 things are contained in a div :**

```
<div style="float: right; margin: 10px;">
here what i want to display on my website
</div>
```

The problem is that i found an example on stackoverflow, but i never wrote preg_match before. **How to do this with the data i want to grabb ?** Thank you

```
<?php   $html = file_get_contents($st_player_cv->getUrlEsl());

preg_match_all(
    'What do i need to write here ?',
    $html,
    $posts, // will contain the data
    PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $premium = $post[1];
    $level = $post[2];

    // do something with data
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a DOM parser instead of regular expressions?

Comment: I don't know, i'm looking for a working solution, never heard of yours, but i could give it a try if you give the more detailled explications ;)

Comment: *sigh* can someone else do it this time please?

Comment: var_dump($posts) gives : array(0) { } so it's not working. Why ? how to fix that please ?

Comment: I don't think they'll like it, I get a _"Due heavy server load, any script based grabbing from the esl webpage has been blocked.<br><br>Thanks for your appreciation."_

Comment: Yeah, it depends, sometimes it shows this message, sometimes not, but until they give an access to their XML api, i must find another solution :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOM way to do it would be

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.esl.eu/fr/player/5178309/');
libxml_clear_errors();

$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xPath->query('//div[@style="float: right; margin: 10px;"]');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

**but** there is a whole slew of JavaScript in the page that modifies the DOM heavily after the page was loaded. Since any PHP script based fetching will not execute any JavaScript, the style we search for in the XPath does not exist yet and we won't get any results (the Regex suggesed by Hannes doesn't work for the same reason). Neither do the level numbers on the badge exist yet.

As Wrikken pointed out in the comments, there also seems to be some mechanism to block certain requests. I had the message once, but I am not sure what triggers it, because I could also fetch page on several occasions.

**To cut a long story short:** you cannot achieve what you are trying to do with this page.

Comment: ok, so i'm only going to retrieve other information like forename / lastname and not the images. i'm going to adapt your solution. Thanks

Comment: @Tristan you can output the entire HTML with `$dom->saveHTML()` to inspect what is returned. This way you will see what is there and what's not. There is a [whole lot of Q&A's on SO about how to use DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+dom+html). Just give it a search or [browse some of my previous answers on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+dom).

Answer (score 1):

this regex `'#<div style="float: right; margin: 10px;">(.*)</div>#'` should do the trick (yeah) but i would advice you to use DOM & XPath.

edit:

Here is an Xpath / DOM Example:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
<body>
    <em>nonsense</em>
    <div style="float: right; margin: 10px;"> here what i want to display on my website </div>
    <div> even more nonsense </div>
</body>
</html>

HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@style="float: right; margin: 10px;"]');
echo $elements->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: var_dump($posts) gives : array(0) { } so it's not working. Why ? how to fix that please ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something more generic

```
  preg_match('/<div[^>]+?>(.*?)<\/div>/', $myhtml, $result);
  echo $result[1] . "\n";
```

`$myhtml` contains the code html you have to analyze. `$result` is the array that contains the regexp and `()` content after the regular expression was applied. `$result[1]` will give you what is between the `<div ... >` and `</div>`.

This way, even if the `<div` differs (class name change or different attributes), it'll still work.